# Warren Buffett's opinion on CFD

Tags: cfd

What is Warren Buffett's option on CFDs?

I am looking for a quotes from a documented source (please provide a reference).

Comment: What research have you already done?

Comment: It should also probably be noted that a lot of rich people don't become rich from what they're preaching. They're usually maintaining their wealth with what they're preaching.

Comment: @RonJohn I have been Googling up to a third page few combinations of sentences like "buffett", "cfd", "berkshire", "contract for differences" etc. I haven't found any quotes (at most, summaries).

Comment: @spam Suggest you search on "derivatives" instead of "CFD". Contracts for differences don't trade in the U.S. due to SEC regulations. IIRC, Buffett has given his opinion on derivatives in general. Suggest you post an answer to your own question when you discover what Buffett would probably think about CFDs, based on what he has said about derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CFDs are a form of derivative. In [the Berkshire Hathaway annual report for 2002](https://www.fintools.com/docs/Warren%20Buffet%20on%20Derivatives.pdf) derivatives are described like this...

> In my view, derivatives are financial weapons of mass destruction, carrying dangers that, while now latent, are potentially lethal.

Comment: This didn't stop Buffett from speculating in options and commodity futures. This also didn't stop Berkshire Hathaway from holding huge positions in convertible securities, warrants and options. Do as I say, not as I do!